# Getting error as ThisApplicatio.workbook does not exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written the  following code to refer to a work book but i am getting the error as i specified

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = ThisApplication.Workbooks[1];
```

I have gone through this page here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Can any one tell what to do

Answer (score 0):

Might need a bit more source code in your example, but it seems as if, you are trying to access it as if it's already opened.  Did you call open?